# How to pull a field with a drilldown capability in SharePoint list using SSIS

Tags: sharepoint-online, ssis

I have got an Auditor field in my SharePoint list, which I can not extract using SSIS.

I think it has drilldown feature incorporated in it.

```
$select=Auditor,Username,AuditDate,Office,Source,Quarter,Region,BU,ClientName,FormStatus,Engagement_Points_Awards,Path
```

Comment: What is the the data type of Auditor field? Person or group or something else

Answer (score 0):

You can use expand if you are using REST.

```
$select=*,Auditor/Title&$expand=Auditor
```

After expanding, you have user's Title, Email and other properties available. For more details you can click here: [Source](https://ajaznusrat.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/using-the-sharepoint-user-type-field-people-or-group-in-list-definition/)

Thanks.